# Deciphering Generics Syntax

Tags: java, generics

I am reading through a question where the signature of the method is given below

```
public static <E extends CharSequence> List<? super E> doIt(List<E> nums)
```

I am unable to decode the syntax. I am very fresh in generics and unable to understand
this part. Doesn't the first part <`E extends CharSequence>` tells what E should be, both
for as an argument and as a return type. But i do see `List<? super E>`, this defines the
bounds for the return type. Can someone help me understand this with an example?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<E extends CharSequence>
```

tells that `E` will be a subtype of `CharSequence`. This tells the compiler that the type argument that will be passed to this method will either be a `CharSequence` or a sub type of that type. This type of bound is known as a parameter bound. I have written [**an article**](https://sayemdb.wordpress.com/2013/07/25/an-introduction-to-generics-in-java-part-5/) on this topic, you can check it out if you like.

```
List<? super E>
```

tells that this method will return a `List` of elements whose type will be either `E` or its super type.

So, all of the following types could be returned from your `doIt` method -

```
// trivial one.
return new ArrayList<E>();

// If F is a super type of E, then the following line is valid too.
return new ArrayList<F>();

// The following will also be valid, since Object is a super type of all
// other types.
return new ArrayList<Object>();
```

`List<? super E>` - this is usually known as a contravariance. [**Check this out**](http://java.dzone.com/articles/covariance-and-contravariance).

Comment: Perfectly fine. I understood the issue. I didn't pay attention that basically first part is telling what E would be. Thanks a lot Sayem. I was confusing for the bounds for argument. The first tells that it is basically what E would be. Perfect Explanation. Thanks a ton.

Comment: @SayemAhmed. There is an error in the very first line of the first part of your generics article in your blog. I've added [a comment there](http://sayemdb.wordpress.com/2013/04/14/an-introduction-to-generics-in-java-part-1/#comment-67). You can check it out.

Comment: @RohitJain was it replaces the type parameter by concrete types. I suppose there is no information about the type information. Was that you were pointing out?

Comment: @benz. Yes. Generics can't provide type check at runtime, because there is no information about types at runtime due to type erasure.

Comment: @RohitJain great Rohit for pointing that out because i found the same mistake as well.